# Setting hadoop.tmp.dir in /tmp

Tags: hadoop

I saw in Hadoop documentation [1](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/core-default.xml) the default value for `hadoop.tmp.dir` is `/tmp/hadoop-${user.name}` but if I set it in that way, when machine restarts, do I loss the data?

I mean, maybe I do not have to set this in the real `/tmp`, but I need to do it in `/home/myuser/tmp/hadoop-${user.name}` ?

Thank you in advance!

**Adding information:**

I set it in /tmp/hadoop-hduser, but the computer was interrupted due to electrical power problems and today I got this message: `Call From java.net.UnknownHostException: hduser-machine: hduser-machine to localhost:54310 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused` and I ran this command `hadoop namenode` and I got this: `ERROR namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /tmp/hadoop-hduser/dfs/name is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.`  And I thought that it was due to the /tmp configuration...

Comment: If machine restarts, you will loose *temporary* data, which is of no use for restarted nodes.

Comment: I added information in my post to explain more the situation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Hadoop is configured to run out of the box. To achieve this, all important (non-temporary) dirs point inside `${hadoop.tmp.dir}`, which in turn points to `/tmp`, which in turn is present on all Linux systems.

As such, you also need to adjust other important paths, see [hdfs-default.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml):

```
dfs.namenode.name.dir
dfs.datanode.data.dir
dfs.namenode.checkpoint.dir
```

They are separate options because in real-world environment it may be feasible to distribute temporary and non-temporary data across different physical storage devices. But if setup is small, then technically yes, you may point `${hadoop.tmp.dir}` into some persistent (non-/tmp) place and ignore what I wrote above.